# white space bottom right in mobile view in chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, containers

How to disable container class just in mobile view ?

Comment: Pls add the working html

Comment: What is your question? Do you want this white space there? Please provide code or a link to the site where we can examine the code. Please see here on how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some closing tags in your code that weren't really closing anything. Even in JSFiddle those tags were displayed in red.

When I removed them like in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sad99s2e/), the white space between the footer and the copyright dissappeared. Not sure if that's what you wanted but it's generally not a good idea to have unnessecary closing tags.

```
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IDEO</title>
    <link href="files/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="files/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="files/img/head.png" rel="shortcut icon">
    <script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link href="files/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="header-container" class="menu-cursor navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <p class="menu-logo">Logo</p>
        <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
    </div>
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul class="small-menus">
                <li><a href="#">Sample</a><a href="#">Sample</a><a href="#">Sample</a><a href="#">Sample</a><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid slider-section">
        <div class="slider col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
            <h1 class="slider-text-typewriting"> <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Sample Text 1", "Sample Text 2", "Sample Text 3", "Sample Text 4" ]'> <span class="wrap"></span> </a> </h1>
            <h1 class="slider-text-typewriting"> <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Sample Text 1", "Sample Text 2", "Sample Text 3", "Sample Text 4" ]'> <span class="wrap"></span> </a> </h1>
            <h1 class="slider-text-typewriting"> <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Sample Text 1", "Sample Text 2", "Sample Text 3", "Sample Text 4" ]'> <span class="wrap"></span> </a> </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 slider-content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            <p></p>
            <p class="HomeHeader-ContactLink"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="Bands">
        <div class="Band ThreeRichTilesBand WithinRowsOfBands">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--small RichTile--left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-ImageContainer">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/blog.png);"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <h3 class="RichTile-TypesRow"><span class="RichTile-Type">Name</span></h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Sample heading text </a></span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--small RichTile--left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-ImageContainer">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/blog.png);"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <h3 class="RichTile-TypesRow"><span class="RichTile-Type">Case Study</span><span class="RichTile-TypeSecond">Name</span></h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Sample heading text </a></span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--small RichTile--left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-ImageContainer">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/blog.png);"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <h3 class="RichTile-TypesRow"><span class="RichTile-Type">blog</span><span class="RichTile-TypeSecond">Blog Name</span></h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Sample heading text </a></span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--</div>
                    <div class="container">-->
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--small RichTile--left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-ImageContainer">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/blog.png);"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <!-- react-text: 102 --><!-- /react-text -->
                            <h3 class="RichTile-TypesRow"><span class="RichTile-Type">Name</span></h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Sample heading text </a></span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--small RichTile--left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-ImageContainer">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/blog.png);"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <!-- react-text: 114 --><!-- /react-text -->
                            <h3 class="RichTile-TypesRow"><span class="RichTile-Type">Case Study</span><span class="RichTile-TypeSecond">Name</span></h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Sample heading text </a></span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--small RichTile--left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-ImageContainer">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/blog.png);"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <!-- react-text: 127 --><!-- /react-text -->
                            <h3 class="RichTile-TypesRow"><span class="RichTile-Type">blog</span><span class="RichTile-TypeSecond">Blog Name</span></h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Sample heading text </a></span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Band FeaturedTileBand FeaturedTileBand--left">
            <div class="FeaturedTileBand-ImageContainer">
                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/blog-main.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="FeaturedTileBand-Content">
                <div class="Grid">
                    <div class="FeaturedTileBand-PlaceholderContainer">
                        <div class="FeaturedTileBand-Placeholder"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="FeaturedTileBand-MainContainer">
                        <div class="FeaturedTileBand-Main">
                            <div class="FeaturedTileBand-MainContent">
                                <h3 class="FeaturedTileBand-TypesRow">
                                    <span class="FeaturedTileBand-Type">questions</span><!-- react-text: 146 --><!-- /react-text -->
                                </h3>
                                <h2 class="FeaturedTileBand-Title"><span><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing </a></span></h2>
                                <div class="FeaturedTileBand-Divider"></div>
                                <p class="FeaturedTileBand-Dek">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p>
                                <a class="Button" href="#">See our response</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- react-text: 153 --><!-- /react-text -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container home-four">
            <h2>Sample Heading</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fa fa-eject"></i>Sample text</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-eject"></i>Sample text</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-eject"></i>Sample text</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-eject"></i>Sample text</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-eject"></i>Sample text</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-eject"></i>Sample text</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-eject"></i>Sample text</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-eject"></i>Sample text</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-eject"></i>Sample text</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-eject"></i>Sample text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container home-five">
            <div>
                <h2>Sample Heading</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="background"></div>
                <h2>
                    <center>Heading Sample Text</center>
                </h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="background"></div>
                <h2>
                    <center>Heading Sample Text</center>
                </h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="background"></div>
                <h2>
                    <center>Heading Sample Text</center>
                </h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="background"></div>
                <h2>
                    <center>Heading Sample Text</center>
                </h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="background"></div>
                <h2>
                    <center>Heading Sample Text</center>
                </h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="background"></div>
                <h2>
                    <center>Heading Sample Text</center>
                </h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="background"></div>
                <h2>
                    <center>Heading Sample Text</center>
                </h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="background"></div>
                <h2>
                    <center>Heading Sample Text</center>
                </h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="background"></div>
                <h2>
                    <center>Heading Sample Text</center>
                </h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Band PairTilesBand lightBlue WithinRowsOfBands">
            <div class="Grid">
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--small RichTile--left">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <!-- react-text: 162 --><!-- /react-text -->
                            <h3 class="RichTile-TypesRow"><span class="RichTile-Type">Case Study</span><span class="RichTile-TypeSecond">Names</span></h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</a></span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--medium RichTile--left">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-ImageContainer">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/corporate.jpg);"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <!-- react-text: 175 --><!-- /react-text -->
                            <h3>Case StudyNames</h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</a></span></h2>
                            <p class="more-link float-right"><a href="#">More <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Band ThreeRichTilesBand WithinRowsOfBands">
            <div class="Grid">
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--small RichTile--left">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-ImageContainer">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/corporate.jpg);"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <!-- react-text: 190 --><!-- /react-text -->
                            <h3 class="RichTile-TypesRow"><span class="RichTile-Type">Case Study</span><span class="RichTile-TypeSecond">Names</span></h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </a></span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--small RichTile--left">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-ImageContainer">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/corporate.jpg);"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <!-- react-text: 203 --><!-- /react-text -->
                            <h3 class="RichTile-TypesRow"><span class="RichTile-Type">Case Study </span><span class="RichTile-TypeSecond">Names</span></h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. </a></span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="RichTile RichTile--small RichTile--left">
                    <div class="RichTile-Content">
                        <div class="RichTile-ImageContainer">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="SmartImage SmartImage--background" style="background-image:url(files/img/corporate.jpg);"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="RichTile-MainContainer">
                            <!-- react-text: 216 --><!-- /react-text -->
                            <h3 class="RichTile-TypesRow"><span class="RichTile-Type">blog</span><span class="RichTile-TypeSecond">Names</span></h3>
                            <h2 class="RichTile-Title"><span><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. </a></span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>

    <!--FOOTER-->
    <link href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--footer start from here-->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 footerleft ">
                    <div class="logofooter"> Logo</div>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley.</p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-map-pin"></i> </p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> </p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> E-mail : </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 paddingtop-bottom">
                    <h6 class="heading7">GENERAL LINKS</h6>
                    <ul class="footer-ul">
                        <li><a href="#"> Career</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Client Gateway</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Ranking</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Case Studies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Frequently Ask Questions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 paddingtop-bottom">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="your@email.com" class="form-control" style="width:200px;">
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Subscribe Now!" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 paddingtop-bottom">
        </div>
    <!--footer start from here-->
    <!--footer start from here-->
    <!--Pulling Awesome Font -->
    <div class="copyright">
        <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="social-network social-circle">
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoRss" title="Rss"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoGoogle" title="Google +"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoLinkedin" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>© 2016 -</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="files/js/index.js"></script>
    <script>
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```